# Why c# switch going in to a different case

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have an enumeration like (a,b,c,d).

```
public enum BeatSession 
{
    on_ended,
    on_new,
    on_hold,
    on_paused,
    on_accepted,
    on_answered,
    on_timed_out,
    on_hanged_up,
    on_initiated,
    unknown
}
```

and a method to do a switch on the enumeration.

```
public static string GetStatusMessage(BeatSession status, string custom_message="")
        {
            string msg = "";
            try
            {
                switch (status)
                {
                    case BeatSession.on_answered:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_ended:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession .on_hanged_up:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_hold:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_new:
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_paused:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_timed_out:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_accepted:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    default:
                        msg = "Unknown";
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            // Override message
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(custom_message))
            {
                msg = custom_message;
            }

            return msg;
        }
```

**Updated**

However, every time I call my method GetStatusMessage(BeatSession.on_ended). 
Even if I pass "on_ended" it goes to "on_answered".

I tried re-arranging "public enum BeatSession". When I passed "on_ended" it now goes to "on_accepted".

**Screenshot**

Notice the watch for session_status varriable.
[image]

Comment: Post the definition of your enumeration.

Comment: Give us proper code to look at. As it stands, your example is lacking anything useful for us to look at.

Comment: please clarify your code. currently the only thing which I can say - "It should work".

Comment: As already stated, without more info, it looks like it should work. One thought though is are you sure that the code recompiled? If your dll doesn't match your source code then Visual Studio can look like it's stepping into the wrong line

Comment: Updated my post. Sorry for being unclear guys. Your reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your function code, replace `enum` by `BeatSession` and it should work

Comment: I updated it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Whats the point of the custom message? Looks like no matter what your switch statement does, if your custom message isn't null or empty, you are returning the custom message anyways. Is that your issue?

Comment: update it again please. show the work code (that could be compiled). or you'll receive a lot of responses which won't help you

Comment: @LeeO., I believe it's pretty clear that the comment `// msg will be here` indicates that the OP intends to fill that with context specfiic messages.

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes...but if he passes in a custom message it will override the message from the switch statement regardless.

Comment: Sorry, guys. Please ignore the return values as I don't have problem with it. My main problem is the switch statement will not fall to the correct case.

Comment: @LeeO., "message from the swich statement"?  I don't follow...  The point is that the switch statement will set the `message` variable.  Each case label will assign that label differently.

Comment: @ShenLance, how can you be sure that your switch statement is not falling in the correct case ? you can't even compile your current code

Comment: post your code when you call the method.

Comment: @Habib, sorry, I already Edited to correct my post. But rest assured that my switch statement is correct on my code. My Post is just a little messed up.

Comment: @KirkWoll and no matter what the switch statement sets the message to, if he passes in a value for custom_message that is what he'll get back. if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(custom_message)) { msg = custom_message; }

Comment: update your question. and change "a" or "b" to the correct value.and the codelines you calling the method "GetStatusMessage".

Comment: Thanks, already updated.

Comment: check my updated answer and tell me..

Comment: are you sure your variable "Session_satus" is parameter's of GetStatusMessage method with type of BeatSession .

Comment: thats a bug.create new project.i test your code it works.

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat], this thread is getting rather long and bordering on noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some code where i do something like this

```
public enum Letters
    {
        A = 1,
        B = 2,
        ...
    }

public void someFunction(int value)
    {
      switch(value)
        {
           case (int)Letters.A: {/* Code */ break;}
           case (int)Letters.B: {/* Code */ break;}
           ...
        }
    }
```

And it works, but i think what you are trying to do is send the enum and use it in the switch in the switch, maybe something like this will work

```
public void someFunction(Letters l)
    {
      switch(l)
        {
           case Letters.A: {/* Code */ break;}
           case Letters.B: {/* Code */ break;}
           ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you take a look my suggestion is the argument of the function should be the same type as your enum, and in the cases use the type of the enum instead of just `enum`

Answer (score 1):

Your current code shouldn't compile, following are the main problems.

First, the method definition contains a parameter `enum status`, you can't do that, It seems you need a parameter of type `BeatSession`, you should modify the function to:

```
public static string GetStatusMessage(BeatSession status, string custom_message="")
{
...
}
```

Next thing in your case statement, you are using `enum.on_answered`, this should be `BeatSession.on_answered`. So your complete function should be:

```
 public static string GetStatusMessage(BeatSession status, string custom_message = "")
        {
            string msg = "";
            try
            {
                switch (status)
                {
                    case BeatSession.on_answered:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_ended:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_hanged_up:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_hold:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_new:
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_paused:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_timed_out:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    case BeatSession.on_accepted:
                        // msg will be here
                        break;
                    default:
                        msg = "Unknown";
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            // Override message
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(custom_message))
            {
                msg = custom_message;
            }

            return msg;
        }
```

EDIT: Since you edited your question with the answer code, you should have any problem with your switch statement, take a look at the following screen shot. 
[image]

Comment: While I agree it's frustrating the OP hasn't provided a SSCCE, this answer doesn't explain why the control flow would go to an unexpected  case label.  This answer only explains why the code wouldn't compile as shown.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will edit my post to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ShenLance, did you try that code, could you post, how are you calling the method ? Use debugger and see what is going on

Comment: @KirkWoll, I wasn't sure if that was the problem, and I don't see any reason that the switch statement shouldn't work now.

Comment: @ShenLance, not sure whats going on, check the edited answer and the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If enum was actually an enum case a: would not pass a compile.

This works for me

```
enum myEnum {A, B, C};

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myEnum thisEnum = myEnum.B;

    switch(thisEnum)
    {
      case myEnum.A:
        // do something
        break;
      case myEnum.B:
       // do something
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well sure, if you're going to be pedantic, the variable reference `enum` would also not compile.  However, I can't conceive of how this will help the OP answer his question.

Comment: @KirkWoll: It's pedantry to post a working code sample in lieu of a meaningful example from the OP?  All he could do is to show a minimal example that works and let the OP compare that to his. +1 to counter the downvote

Comment: Enum is passed to my function which has the switch(Enum e) statement on it.

Comment: @EdS. -- I didn't downvote.  But in answer to your question, I don't understand how this could help inform the OP as to the nature of his problem.  Would you care to expound?   (Greg's suggestion in the comments, for example, seems likely to me, and this answer would not help the OP)

Comment: @EdS., more importantly, I feel like the OP hadn't yet (though now he has) provided enough info to intelligently answer this question.  To be frank, I dislike (quick draw) answers that are techinically correct but stand little chance of helping the questioner.  This is because SO strongly publicizes questions with unupvoted anwers and answers like these frustrate that workflow.

Comment: Sorry about it guys, I couldn't provide more info to my problem as that is all i have to describe it. But additionally, not sure if this will help. My OS is windows 7. The Enum is on different class library. And I'm pretty sure I compiled it. Tried restarting my PC but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. Here is what I did. I modified my Enum to be like this.

```
public enum BeatSession 
{
    on_ended=0,
    on_new=1,
    on_hold=2,
    on_paused=3,
    on_accepted=4,
    on_answered=5,
    on_timed_out=6,
    on_hanged_up=7,
    on_initiated=8,
    unknown=9
}
```

So I think what happened was at some point during runtime or compile time the values on my Enum get's scrambled. So I tried setting the value manually and that did the trick.

Thanks Everyone for your reply.

Comment: why you didnt check @saul672 's answer.?

Comment: sorry, because the discussion is very long already I didn't notice his answer. Yea, I will check it.

Answer (score -1):

maybe your code is like :

```
 public static string GetStatusMessage(BeatSession status, string custom_message = "")
    {
        string msg = "";
        try
        {
            switch (status)
            {
                case BeatSession.on_answered:
                    // msg will be here

                case BeatSession.on_ended:
                    // msg will be here
                    break;
 .....
```

if you pass BeatSession.on_answered then in swith (think you missed "break;") goes to BeatSession.on_ended.